# Should data exceeding 4MB sent to BinaryWrite() ever be chunked?

Tags: winapi, iis, visual-c++, asp-classic

I have some old code that writes binary data to the Response object's BinaryWrite() method (Classic ASP).  It sends the data in 4MB chunks to BinaryWrite(), but now I'm wondering whether that ever worked and whether BinaryWrite() is even designed to handle serial chunks of data (or whether it should only be called, at most, once per page request).

I found this link that describes how the "Response Buffering Limit" should be increased, and increasing it seems to have solved the issues I was seeing (without using my chunking code at all).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-500-response-binarywrite

This is the old code in question:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CQVMActiveHost::WriteData (const VOID* pcvData, DWORD cbData, __out DWORD* pcbWritten)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    DISPPARAMS dispParams = {0};
    VARIANT vWrite = {0}, vResult = {0};

    Check(LoadResponseObject());

    dispParams.cArgs = 1;
    dispParams.rgvarg = &vWrite;

    if(m_fSupportsBinary)
    {
        SAFEARRAYBOUND Bound;
        DWORD cbRemaining = cbData;

        Bound.lLbound = 0;
        vWrite.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1;

        while(0 < cbRemaining)
        {
            PVOID pbPtr;

            Bound.cElements = min(cbRemaining, 4 * 1024 * 1024);
            vWrite.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, &Bound);
            CheckAlloc(vWrite.parray);

            SafeArrayAccessData(vWrite.parray, &pbPtr);
            CopyMemory(pbPtr, pcvData, Bound.cElements);
            SafeArrayUnaccessData(vWrite.parray);

            VariantClear(&vResult);
            Check(m_pResponse->Invoke(m_dispidBinaryWrite, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dispParams, &vResult, NULL, NULL));
            SafeArrayDestroy(vWrite.parray);
            vWrite.parray = NULL;

            pcvData = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(pcvData) + Bound.cElements;
            cbRemaining -= Bound.cElements;
        }

        vWrite.vt = VT_EMPTY;
    }
    else
```

I've seen a couple different behaviors with the old code.  In some tests, the first call to BinaryWrite() succeeded, but subsequent calls failed with the "exception occurred" HRESULT.  In other tests, the calls seemed to succeed, but the browser didn't receive any data.

Are there any scenarios where it would make sense to make multiple calls to BinaryWrite() with chunked data?

Or should I always increase the "Response Buffering Limit" value to more than 4MB and just make a single call to BinaryWrite() with the full data?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the purple note on [`BinaryWrite()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524318(v=vs.90)) - "As a result of this buffering, the ASP application should not try to send unreasonable amounts of data in a single `BinaryWrite`, but rather break it into fragments so as to avoid running out of buffer space".

Comment: Should I chunk large data into segments that are smaller than the 4MB limit?  Maybe that was the issue?

Comment: If I send a "Content-Length" header that indicates the full size of the data to be sent through BinaryWrite(), then the browser reports that the connection was reset.  Strangely, it seems to work better if I omit the "Content-Length" header, and that makes no sense to me.

Comment: You shouldn't pass the `Content-Length` header as it will handle that itself, that's probably what's causing the issue.

Comment: Originally, I wasn't trying to send the "Content-Length" header.  That was just part of one test.  So now I adjusted the "Response Buffering Limit" back to 4MB in IIS, and I'm again seeing the behavior where the first BinaryWrite() call succeeds, but the next call returns 0x80020009.  Does this mean I should break the large data into fragments smaller than 4MB each?

Comment: Nope...  If I break the data into 1MB chunks, then the BinaryWrite() calls succeed only until 4MB have been sent.  Once it exceeds the "Response Buffering Limit" value, then it fails.

Comment: Okay, adding a Flush() call might have fixed it.

Comment: That’s pretty much how response buffering is meant to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to wonder whether the `Response.Buffer` property was `false` when I originally wrote the code above.  What I've found is the following:

1. The `Response.BinaryWrite()` method MAY be called multiple times per page request.
2. If a large amount of data is to be returned to the client, then split the data into multiple calls to `Response.BinaryWrite()`.
3. The "Response Buffering Limit" value in IIS (for ASP) is 4MB by default.
4. If `Response.Buffer` is `true`, then multiple calls to `Response.BinaryWrite()` may be made until the total data reaches the "Response Buffering Limit" value.  At that point, `Response.Flush()` MUST be called.  Otherwise, attempting to send more data results in error 0x80020009.
5. If `Response.Buffer` is `false`, then do NOT call `Response.Flush()`, but do split the data into multiple (smaller) calls to `Response.BinaryWrite()`.
6. As an example, I was trying to send a 12MB file using multiple calls to `Response.BinaryWrite()` with each chunk being 4MB.  Buffering was enabled, so the first call succeeded, but the next call failed.  Raising the "Response Buffering Limit" to 16MB "solved" the issue but increased the buffering allocation for ASP.

Ultimately, I've modified my chunking code to first query the `Response.Buffer` property.  The data is always sent in smaller fragments to `Response.BinaryWrite()`, but `Response.Flush()` is also called if buffering is enabled.

Finally, don't set the `Content-Length` header.  The browser may not know how many bytes will be downloaded, but it will receive the file correctly without manually setting that header.  Setting that header breaks the download.

And the final ASP script:

```
    function GoDownloadFile (strPath)
    {
        var idxName = strrchr(strPath, '/');
        var strFolder = left(strPath, idxName + 1);
        var strFile = right(strPath, len(strPath) - (idxName + 1));

        var oFS = Security.GetChannel().OpenFileSystem();
        oFS.Folder = strFolder;

        Response.ContentType = Host.GetContentType(strFile);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; FileName=\"" + strFile + "\"");

        Host.BinaryWrite(oFS.ReadFile(strFile));
    }
```